# Interbase sql precision calculation

Tags: sql, interbase

Calculating 5.5 / 100 by a calculator gives me 0.055

Calculating with Interbase SQL gives me 0.05.

What can I do to get the right answer which is 0.055

eg.

```
select stockid, (price1 * (Percentage_fig / 100)) as percentage_val
from stock
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROUND(CAST(1 * (5.5 / 100) as float), 3)`

3 is the number of digits after the point.